# Giving image statically by reading image from assets folder and passing to the tensorflow object detection android

Tags: python, android, tensorflow

I am currently working on tensorflow object detection on android by following this link
https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android
Here I have camera access. Now I want to send image statically or taking the image from folder in android and should returns the output as bounding box on the given image and its label.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the [tflite](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/detection/tflite) folder, and rewrite [DetectorActivity.java](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/detection/DetectorActivity.java) with your own use case scenario. For example, you could follow the steps below.

1. Create the interpreter same as the [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/detection/DetectorActivity.java#L99).
2. Load your image from assets into bitmap.
3. Apply proper preprocessing, such as rotation and resize, as needed. Load the bitmap in the same way as the [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/detection/DetectorActivity.java#L181).
4. Retrieve the bounding box by [getLocation()](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/detection/DetectorActivity.java#L202).